# Не работает показ одной новости Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, чпу, компоненты

не могу настроить чпу отображения новостей. Показывает код 404
Необходим вывод новостей типа  `#SITE_DIR#/news/#ELEMENT_CODE#`

Создал страницу  `#SITE_DIR#/news/detail.php` 
Добавил в нее компонент " bitrix:news.detail " и настроил ID новости `={$_REQUEST["ELEMENT_CODE"]}` 
В правилах обработки адресов указал

Условие  `#^/news/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)#`

Компонент  `bitrix:news.detail`

Файл  `/news/detail.php`

Правило  `ELEMENT_CODE=$1`

При переходе по ссылке "новость детально" открывается 404.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на каком этапе совершил ошибку.

Если ставлю  в настройках компонента `"USE_PERMISSIONS" => "Y"`,
получаю ошибку `У Вас нет прав на просмотр полного текста`. Если поставить `"USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N"` то 404 ошибка. 
Такая новость в инфоблоках есть и она активна. В чем может быть причина?

Вот настройки компонента bitrix:news.detail

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.detail","",Array(
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "USE_SHARE" => "Y",
        "SHARE_HIDE" => "N",
        "SHARE_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "SHARE_HANDLERS" => array("delicious"),
        "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN" => "",
        "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY" => "",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "news",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "3",
        "ELEMENT_ID" => "",
        "ELEMENT_CODE" => $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_CODE"],
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "FIELD_CODE" => "",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => "",
        "IBLOCK_URL" => "news.php?ID=#IBLOCK_ID#\"",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "Y",
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "N",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "Y",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N",
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "Y",
        "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => array("1","2","3"),
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "Y",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "Y",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK" => "",
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N"
    )
);?>
```

Comment: Доступ для всех к инфоблоку есть?

Comment: @NikolajSarry да Все пользователи - Чтение, Администраторы - полный доступ

Comment: Откуда переходите в детальную новость? Где отображается список? Какой там компонент?

Comment: Судя по всему у компонента в котором список вы в пути к детальной странице не указали, что это `/news/detail.php'

Comment: @NikolajSarry  из страницы с компонентом bitrix:news.list там список всех новостей, из него перехожу в одну новость по ссылке mysite.com/news/onda_novost

Comment: @NikolajSarry очень может быть Николай, сейчас проверю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94337/discussion-between-nikolaj-sarry-and-dmitriy).

Comment: "ID новости `={$_REQUEST["ELEMENT_ID"]}`" но `#SITE_DIR#/news/#ELEMENT_CODE#`. Никому не кажется что `ID` это не `CODE` ни разу?

Comment: @u_mulder неправильно здесь написал, в компоненте cтоит ={$_REQUEST["ELEMENT_CODE"]}, все вроде правильно

Comment: Все разобрался, стоял неправильный id компонента в настройках, всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
"USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N"
```